# Single word to say I've watched them all

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that encompasses the idea that I've watched everything there is on TV such as "I've outdone them all"? But outdoing feels implies an active action whereas watching movie can be more of a passive word. Looking for suggestions!

Comment: You should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: You might say in a humorous fashion "I've finished Netflix" or "I've finished the internet". But you need to say exactly what you're looking for, and if you want something joky, colloquial, or formal and serious.